# Directions app ambiguous member

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a directions ap but I'm getting an ambiguous to member of 'directionsusinggoogle' error. It uses google places api to calculate directions, etc. Here is my code. And here is an image of the error.

[image]

```
  @IBAction func ClickToGo(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if isValidPincode() {
        mapManager.directionsUsingGoogle(from: txtFrom.text!, to: txtTo.text!) { (route,directionInformation, boundingRegion, error) -> () in

            if(error != nil){
                print(error)
            }
            else{
                let pointOfOrigin = MKPointAnnotation()
                pointOfOrigin.coordinate = route!.coordinate
                pointOfOrigin.title = directionInformation?.object(forKey: "start_address") as! NSString as String
                pointOfOrigin.subtitle = directionInformation?.object(forKey: "duration") as! NSString as String

                let pointOfDestination = MKPointAnnotation()
                pointOfDestination.coordinate = route!.coordinate
                pointOfDestination.title = directionInformation?.object(forKey: "end_address") as! NSString as String
                pointOfDestination.subtitle = directionInformation?.object(forKey: "distance") as! NSString as String

                let start_location = directionInformation?.object(forKey: "start_location") as! NSDictionary
                let originLat = start_location.object(forKey: "lat")?.doubleValue
                let originLng = start_location.object(forKey: "lng")?.doubleValue

                let end_location = directionInformation?.object(forKey: "end_location") as! NSDictionary
                let destLat = end_location.object(forKey: "lat")?.doubleValue
                let destLng = end_location.object(forKey: "lng")?.doubleValue

                let coordOrigin = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: originLat!, longitude: originLng!)
                let coordDesitination = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destLat!, longitude: destLng!)

                pointOfOrigin.coordinate = coordOrigin
                pointOfDestination.coordinate = coordDesitination
                if let web = self.drawMap {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.removeAllPlacemarkFromMap(shouldRemoveUserLocation: true)
                    web.add(route!)
                    web.addAnnotation(pointOfOrigin)
                    web.addAnnotation(pointOfDestination)
                    web.setVisibleMapRect(boundingRegion!, animated: true)
                    print(directionInformation)
                    self.tableData = directionInformation!
                    }
                }
            }
        } }
}
```

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/varshylmobile/MapManager/blob/master/MapManager.swift

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using https://github.com/varshylmobile/MapManager/blob/master/MapManager.swift and have converted it to **Swift 3**, the API has the following signatures:

```
func directionsUsingGoogle(from:NSString, to:NSString,
    directionCompletionHandler:DirectionsCompletionHandler)

func directionsUsingGoogle(from:CLLocationCoordinate2D, to:CLLocationCoordinate2D,
    directionCompletionHandler:DirectionsCompletionHandler)

func directionsUsingGoogle(from:CLLocationCoordinate2D, to:NSString,
    directionCompletionHandler:DirectionsCompletionHandler)
```

Notice the `NSString`, hence:

```
mapManager.directionsUsingGoogle(
    from: txtFrom.text! as NSString,
    to: txtTo.text! as NSString,
    directionCompletionHandler: {(
        _ route:MKPolyline?,
        _ directionInformation:NSDictionary?,
        _ boundingRegion:MKMapRect?,
        _ error:String?) in
        ...
    }
)
```

Comment: OT, but I'm curious why the compiler message is 'ambiguous member...' rather than something like 'no members with type String, String...' exists

Comment: swift architect i was wondering if you could help me with something else

Comment: Certainly - Post your question on Stack Overflow and place a link to it here